# See users in Google Analytics who saw both a webpage and a contact page (without goals)

Tags: google-analytics

My client's site did not have goals set up previously but has years of historical data in its raw view. The site has a bunch of resource articles in its blog, and it has a contact page. I want to see which resource articles were most popular AND that sent traffic to the contact page. A report on behavior gives me all of the URIs and the number of pageviews they received. How can I filter this report to get just pageviews (or users) that ALSO saw the contact page during the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a segment in with the contact page as the filter, what it reports back will be sessions that included a pageview of the contact page. then you can filter in a page report to just see the resource articles